# Adhoc Pre-filter condition not working with Adhoc filter in JasperReports Server 6.3.0

Tags: jasperserver, adhoc

Using **supermart** sample Domain, I've applied Pre-filter condition on a "Product Name" field as **Product Name contains American**  during Ad hoc view creation in Jasper server and created an Ad hoc view with "Product Name" field dragged onto Rows. This will list out all the product names that contains "American" as expected but when i Right click on "Product Name" field and select "Create filter" option, i am seeing all the Product names displayed in the newly created filter. I want to display only those product names that satisfy the Pre-filter condition.

Could some shed some light on this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hi,
You can create a domain and define a pre-filter in the domain. In that case, everything should work. But it will be just a workaround.

Comment: Hi Spachynskyi - thanks for the reply. We cannot make any changes at the domain level as it is accessible by different Tenants and impacts other unintended users/Adhoc views. So, only option is to configure it at the Ad hoc level.